# Error Code: 3618. st_simplify(LINESTRING, ...) has not been implemented (and yet it works fine by doing ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText()))

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial, mysql-8.0, spatial-query

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT ST_Simplify(SHAPE, 1.0)
FROM nhdflowline
WHERE OGR_FID = 12701;
```

Running that gives me the following error:

```
Error Code: 3618. st_simplify(LINESTRING, ...) has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems.
```

However, if I do this, it works just fine:

```
SELECT ST_Simplify(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(SHAPE)), 1.0)
FROM nhdflowline
WHERE OGR_FID = 12701;
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. I can't run `ST_Simplify` directly on a geometry - I have to convert it to text and then *back* to a geometry to run `ST_Simplify`?

Am I missing something? I'm running MySQL 8.0.22.

Comment: as it says it is not implemented yet, so try 8.0,.26 or wait and use what the hint tells you to

Comment: @nbk - Michael Entin nailed it. There are multiple types of geometries. simply is supported for some of them but not for all of them. I did not realize that there were multiple types of geometries when I posted the question but the fact that there were is indicative of the fact that I was indeed "missing something".

Comment: as the error mesage cöearöy states, that you need forst convert iot to the right format that ST_Simplify understands. As it it possible as you shpown in you second query, it will be implemented and so a internal con version will take place.test it with dbfiddklle which uses 8.0,.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the last part of the error message: "has not been implemented for geographic spatial reference systems".

There are two kinds of reference systems (SRID): geographic, with computations on sphere, and projected, with computations on plane map.

When you do ST_AsText, and then back to geometry, you remove SRID, so the geometry which used to be associated with geographic (i.e. spherical) geometry, now has planar semantics and SRID=0. It's semantics changed for MySQL. What used to be lat:lng on sphere now are just two coordinates on plane.

Your version of MySQL implements simplify for planar (projected) geometry, but not for geographic SRID. You can use simplify on plane, but units of distance are different (usually degrees vs meters), as well as semantics (one degree along meridian is bigger in meters than one degree along parallel if you are far from equator).